# Testing QT QML application using scripting language

Tags: qt, automation, qml

Is there any other way to do automation testing to a QT QML application or read the elements of QT and control it from an other application without squish or any licensed tools?

If yes, is there an documentations for it or sample project?

It may be duplicate, but an answer will be very helpful.

Comment: Have you had a look at Qt Quick Test already? You can use QML (and hence JavaScript) to test other QML code.

Comment: @Corristo - Can I use QT Quick outside of the actual application? I think it is for unit testing.

Comment: You can't do black-box end-to-end testing with Qt Quick Test if that is what you're trying to do, but you sure can do white-box end-to-end testing, that is have the test-runner `main` function set up the entire application just like the real `main` main would. The only difference then would be that the test runner uses different test QML  files (in which you'd instantiate your real main QML component) instead of the main QML component that is uses by your application.